# Embed + select menu в discord.py[Закрыто]

Tags: python, discord.py

**Пытаюсь сделать сочетание embed + select menu, но не могу убрать заголовок перед select menu.**

Если просто уберу заголовок в select menu, то получу ошибку: Cannot send empty message.

*Скрин 1 — нужный результат, скрин 2 — мой результат.*

**Нашёл как это реализовать в discord.js** — [Кликабельно*](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#select-menus)

> This is a message with components — заголовок, о котором идёт речь

[image: Как мне нужно]

[image: Как у меня получилось]

---

#### Мой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def roles(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Автоматическая выдача ролей',
        description = '**Вы можете самостоятельно получить роль вашего сервера выбрав ее название в меню. \
            \n При выборе определённых ролей Вам будут открываться соответствующие текстовые и голосовые каналы. \
            \n Если Вы не играете ни на одном из серверов, то Вам будет доступен** **__только общий чат.__**\n \
            \n **Роли доступные для получения в данный момент:** \
            \n — <@&882204001393852458>\n — <@&882204002681499698>',
        color = 0xfff700,
    )

    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://images8.alphacoders.com/102/1026336.jpg')
    embed.set_footer(text='© Bumbazzz')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


    msg = await ctx.send(
        'This is a message with components',
        components = [
            Select(
                placeholder = "Выберите Ваш сервер",
                options = [
                    SelectOption(label = "Sunrise", value = "Sunrise", description = "GTA 5 RP | Sunrise", emoji = ''),
                    SelectOption(label = "Rainbow", value = "Rainbow", description = "GTA 5 RP | Rainbow", emoji = '')
                ]
            )
        ]
    )

    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    await bot.send(content = f"Роль {interaction.value[0]} была вадана!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Никак, так как параметр content обязательный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо параметра content можно поставить само embed-сообщение

```
@bot.command()  # Выдача ролей при помощи select menu
async def roles(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    give_roles = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Автоматическая выдача ролей',
        description = '**Вы можете самостоятельно получить роль вашего сервера выбрав ее название в меню. \
            \n При выборе определённых ролей Вам будут открываться соответствующие текстовые и голосовые каналы. \
            \n Если Вы не играете ни на одном из серверов, то Вам будет доступен** **__только общий чат.__**\n \
            \n **Роли доступные для получения в данный момент:** \
            \n — <@&889169786121097296>\n — <@&881961587559243877>\n — <@&881962331544891443>',
        color = 0xfff700,)

    give_roles.set_thumbnail(url='https://images8.alphacoders.com/102/1026336.jpg')
    give_roles.set_footer(text='© Bumbazzz')

    await ctx.send(
        embed=give_roles,
        components = [
            Select(
                placeholder = "Выберите Ваш сервер",
                options = [
                    SelectOption(label = "Insquad", value = "Insquad", description = "GTA 5 RP | InSquad", emoji = ''),
                    SelectOption(label = "Sunrise", value = "Sunrise", description = "GTA 5 RP | Sunrise", emoji = ''),
                    SelectOption(label = "Rainbow", value = "Rainbow", description = "GTA 5 RP | Rainbow", emoji = '')
                ]
            )
        ]
    )


    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    # member = ctx.member()
    # await member.add_roles(interaction.values[0])
    await interaction.send(content=f"Роль {interaction.values[0]} была вадана!", embed=embed)
```

Comment: Не бейте за отступы, тут уже сам stack сломался